# Error propagation of angle between vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis, error-propagation

Say $a$ and $b$ are vectors (say in $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $\alpha$ is the **angle** between $a$ and $b$, say defined as $\alpha:= arcos(\frac{ab}{|a||b|})$.

### Question

If one **shakes** $a$ and $b$, then how much shakes alpha? 
In other words, if $a$ and $b$ have additional **error** information, how are these errors propagated to $\alpha$?

### Example

Say $a$ and $b$ are averages of independent, normally distributed point clouds $A$ and $B$ and errors are given by standard deviations for each dimension of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The textbook by Halsar and Mahadevan is a good introduction to the topic. It's an expensive book though and it may be a good idea to see if there's a used copy on eBay. http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471331198,subjectCd-ST23.html

Comment: Thanks, is that a reference for *SD of a contiuous function of several normally distributed independent variables*? Could you give a reference where to find this if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may restate your problem, you have an angle formed by two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ constrained to $\mathbb R^2$, and whose components $a_x,a_y$ and $b_x,b_y$ are all normally distributed variables each with known means and standard deviations.

$$
\alpha=\cos^{-1}\Bigg(\frac{a_xb_x+a_yb_y}{\sqrt{(a_x^2+a_y^2)(b_x^2+b_y^2)}}\Bigg)
$$

The standard deviation of the angle is then given by

$$
\sigma_\alpha = \sqrt{
\Big(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial a_x}\Big|_{\mu} \sigma_{a_x}\Big)^2
+
\Big(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial a_y}\Big|_{\mu} \sigma_{a_y}\Big)^2
+
\Big(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial b_x}\Big|_{\mu} \sigma_{b_x}\Big)^2
+
\Big(\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial b_y}\Big|_{\mu} \sigma_{b_y}\Big)^2
}
$$

where the subscript $\mu$ implies that the partial derivatives must be evaluated at the (known) mean values of $a_x,a_y$, $b_x$, and $b_y$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Is the $\sigma_\alpha$ really the SD of $\alpha$? In other words: does the Gauss error propagation, that you suggested as I understand, always produce the SD of the function?

Comment: Yes it is, and assuming that you've calculated the partial derivatives correctly below which I didn't check (but which looks OK at first glance), then yes your formula as expanded is correct.

Comment: Remember that the expression for the standard deviation above is correct to within a first order approximation of $\alpha$ in terms of the angles. It can be derived by taking the expectation of the square of the Taylor series truncated after the first term.

Comment: Could you add a reference, where I can read more about the SD of a contiuous function of several normally distributed independent variables and how that SD then depends on the SDs of the variables?

Comment: So the $\sigma_\alpha$ can be derived by taking the **expectation of the square of the Taylor series truncated after the first term**. My questions: (1) why expectation of the square, (2) you take the Taylor series of $\alpha$ for that and truncate it after the 1st term?

Comment: In case I want an upper estimate of the SD of $\alpha$ I should then add the remainder of that truncated Taylor series?

Comment: The variance is defined as the second central moment $<(f-\mu_f)^2>$. (The mean would be the first raw moment). Including more terms in the Taylor's Seriesexpansion of $f({\vec x})$ only gives you a better estimate of the statistical metrics (not an upper bound).